# Assistance with turnery query

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have a conditional that works but when i try to compress it to a turnery i get errors and for the life of me i cant see where.

This is the function that runs:

```
def alphabet_position(text):
    output = ""
    dict = {'a':'1','b':'2','c':'3','d':'4','e':'5','f':'6','g':'7','h':'8','i':'9','j':'10','k':'11','l':'12','m':'13','n':'14','o':'15','p':'16','q':'17','r':'18','s':'19','t':'20','u':'21','v':'22','w':'23','x':'24','y':'25','z':'26'}
    input = list(text.lower())
    for i in input:
        if i not in dict:
            next
        else:
            output += (dict[i]+" ")
    return output.rstrip()
```

An this is what i am trying to compress to:

```
for i in input:
    output += (dict[i]+" ") if i in dict else next
```

But it wont run and i get this error as output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    test.assert_equals(alphabet_position("The sunset sets at twelve o' clock."), "20 8 5 19 21 14 19 5 20 19 5 20 19 1 20 20 23 5 12 22 5 15 3 12 15 3 11")
  File "/home/codewarrior/solution.py", line 6, in alphabet_position
    output += (dict[i]+" ") if i in dict else next
TypeError: must be str, not builtin_function_or_method
```

Comment: What is `next`?  That isn't a keyword?

Comment: Its from PHP it kinda slipped in lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [[Python 3.Docs]: Built-in functions - **next**(*iterator[, default]*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next). You have absolutely no need to call it.

**Note**: you are shadowing a couple of builtin names like *dict*, *input*. Don't do that, as you might experience (funky) errors as your codebase grows.

Your uncompressed form works, but not because of what you think. Calling *next* is redundant and useless. Your loop is equivalent to:

```py
for i in input_list:
    if i in dictionary:
        output += (dictionary[i] + " ")
```

As for the compressed form, you meant:

```py
output += (dictionary[i] + " ") if i in dictionary else ""  # NOT next
```

But you could do even better: a single line having a list comprehension, wrapped by a string:

```py
output = " ".join([dictionary[i] for i in input_list if i in dictionary])
```

and from there, the whole function could look like (by getting rid of the helper dictionary, and using a property of (lower case letter) characters *ASCII* codes):

```py
def alphabet_position(text):
    return " ".join(str(ord(c) - 0x60) for c in text.lower() if c.islower())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check and update on the occurence of the character on the basis of dictionary, you can do:

```
def alphabet_position(text):
    dict = {'a':'1','b':'2','c':'3','d':'4','e':'5','f':'6','g':'7','h':'8','i':'9','j':'10','k':'11','l':'12','m':'13','n':'14','o':'15','p':'16','q':'17','r':'18','s':'19','t':'20','u':'21','v':'22','w':'23','x':'24','y':'25','z':'26'}
    input = list(text.lower())
    output=[dict[i] for i in text if i in dict]
    output=" ".join(output)
    return output
```

Answer (score 0):

If you replace next with a `''`, your code works fine:

```
for i in input:
    output += (dict[i]+" ") if i in dict else ''
```

I'm not sure what next is supposed to be, but it isn't a python keyword.